# Redirecting a Domain without Changing URL

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect a domain to point to one of my other domains without changing the URL. Whenever I save the code I am running into a 500 internal server error.  I am currently using the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain1.com/ [P]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I am trying to have domain2 point to domain1.

I have no experience in .htaccess, am I making a common mistake with this code?

Thanks

Comment: `[P]`flag requires `mod_proxy` to be enabled

Comment: I took the ```[p]``` out of my code and it now redirects to the domain I want it to, but it changes the URL.

Comment: Unless it's the same `VirtualHost`, it cannot be done without `mod_proxy`. Look for  `Absolute URL` in the _Substitutions_ section in the following [reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). It "always" forces an external redirect.